# Only 1 div toggle status jQuery (close others)

Tags: jquery, toggle, status

I'm currently working with fadeToggle to show/hide certain elements and what I got here seems to do the job quite well! When a span element is clicked that's inside an li element it fadetoggles the next div that's inside the li element. Pretty nifty I would say!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggle_hide').hide();

        $("#background_absolute_content li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(){
            $(this).next("div").fadeToggle(200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**But ofcourse there's allways something you just can't seem to figure out!**

I only want one div to be toggled and currently they don't close after a next span here you can see the website. If you click on the linkedin and the facebook icon next to the line "now compatible with" you'll see what I mean.

**So is there a way to close the div when a next span is clicked.**

**Note I use this method aswell on the config icon on the top right.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never been a fan of the toggle commands. I usually manually fadeOut/fadeIn...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggle_hide').hide();

        $("#background_absolute_content li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.toggle_hide').fadeOut(200, function(){ 
                $this.next("div").fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice. Smooth transition rather than **POOF**, no more div. Kudos. :)

Comment: Ha. Not my question, or I would. :D

Comment: Wow... maybe I should go to sleep... obviously getting tired... haha

Comment: Thanks for the (very) fast respond! I feel kind of bad, just asking around but I've been trying to find out an propper solution. The example above works like 90%. 

The problem is that when you click between the the icons the div that should fadeIn does a quick flash because you say to close it first (hope that makes sence).

I think the solution has something to do with .sibbling (or another selector) since the div's that have to toggle all resides in different li elements in the same ul element.

http://no-illusions.nl/projecten/friendchamp/backend.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new problem... I also looked at the site and it didn't look bad...

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed the problem and uploaded it :).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a quick and dirty fix is to call your hide method before showing the one relevant to what was clicked. Insert your method:

```
$('.toggle_hide').hide();
```

before you call:

```
$(this).next("div").fadeToggle(200);
```